# why Request["parameter"] is null in webmethod?

Tags: asp.net, request, jtable

I am working on asp.net. Using jTable and it's working fine if I'm giving listaction to to some page (and adding code in pageload). If I'm adding webmethod to the same page's code behind file for listaction then getting

> HttpContext.Current.Request["frmdate"] = null

HTML Code

```
 <div id="dSaleBillContainer" style="padding-top: 115px;"></div>
```

Code of jTable

```
 $('#dSaleBillContainer').jtable({
                title: 'Sale Bills (User : <label id="user"></label>)',
                paging: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                pageSizes: [10, 25, 50, 75],
                sorting: true,
                defaultSorting: 'S01F01 DESC',
                selecting: true, //Enable selecting
                multiselect: true, //Allow multiple selecting
                selectingCheckboxes: true, //Show checkboxes on first column
                selectOnRowClick: false,
                openChildAsAccordion: true,
                actions: {
                    listAction: 'dSaleBills.aspx/List'
                    //listAction: 'GetSalesBill.aspx?Mode=List' - this way working perfect with same code which is calling another page and issue is with same page code behind webmethod

                },
               .......
        });
```

How I fill data and actually this method is working properly

```
 $('#btnLoad').click(function (e) {
            debugger;
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#dSaleBillContainer').jtable('load', {
                user: $('#ddlsbUsers').val(),
                frmdate: $('#<%=txtFrmDate.ClientID %>').val(),
                todate: $('#<%=txtToDate.ClientID %>').val(),
                route: $('#ddlRoute').val() == "0" ? $('#ddlRoute').val() : $('#ddlRoute option:selected').text(),
                searchText: $('#<%= txtSearchText.ClientID %>').val()
            });
            var ddlsbUsers = $("[id*=ddlsbUsers]");
            $("#user").html(ddlsbUsers.find("option:selected").text());
        });

        //Load all records when page is first shown
        $('#btnLoad').click();
```

Code of webmethod

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static String List()
        {
            string Result;
            string a = HttpContext.Current.Request["frmdate"];
            string frmdate = HttpContext.Current.Request["frmdate"].ToString();
        }
```

What's the solution for this?

Is there any better solution for doing this? Answer will help me a lot.........

Comment: Where is that frmdate sent?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: Code updated...and this works fine by calling to another bt not working with same page codebehind webmethod..